# Receiving PHP Parse error for common.inc but the include command (indicated in the error) is not in the file

Tags: php, drupal, php-include

Our site is externally hosted.  It's using Drupal (very outdated and the higher ups are reluctant to upgrade).  We have several pages that connect to a database on a different server (hosted by a different company) to display scheduling information.

Recently the company hosting our Drupal site upgraded PHP and it blew out all of our pages accessing the database.  After much wrangling, I believe that I've corrected the connection issues but now I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE) in /imedia/users/sc-drupal/htdocs/includes/common.inc(1695) : eval()'d code on line 1

Here are the first few lines of the common.inc file

```
line 1:<?php 
line 2:// $Id: common.inc,v 1.756.2.96 2010/08/11 20:35:47 goba Exp $
line 3:
line 4:/**
line 5: * @file
line 6: * Common functions that many Drupal modules will need to reference.
line 7: *
line 8: * The functions that are critical and need to be available even when serving
line 9: * a cached page are instead located in bootstrap.inc.
line 10:*/

line 11:/**
line 12: * Return status for saving which involved creating a new item.
line 13: */
line 14: define('SAVED_NEW', 1);
...
```

**For those that might claim that this is a duplicate questions, please see the notes, below.  `include` is not anywhere near line 1!**

My thoughts are that the `common.inc` file is not the problem.  All other pages are working so I would think that would point the problem to the PHP file for the page, which has the error.

The problem with that: nothing was changed in that file either.

Can anyone point me in a direction to trouble shoot this?

```
<?php
$page_name = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],0,strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],"?"));

 // START TIME when file loads
$start_time = getmicrotime();

/***************************************************
SCRUB USER SUBMITTED DATA
Do it once here, rather than multiple times in each of the included files
***************************************************/
if(preg_match("/\w/",$_GET[searchInput]))
{
  $_GET[searchInput]=trim($_GET[searchInput]);

}

$_GET[search_type] = strip_tags($_GET[search_type]);

foreach($_GET as $gk=>$gv) // 'gk' == 'get key', 'gv'== 'get value'
{
  //echo "$gk $gv<br>";
  $_GET[$gk] = addslashes(strip_tags($gv));
}

$startMoAry= explode(" " , $_GET[startMonth]);
$endMoAry= explode(" " , $_GET[endMonth]);
$start_ts=strtotime($startMoAry[0]."".$_GET[startDate].",".$startMoAry[1]);

$end_ts=strtotime($endMoAry[0]." ".$_GET[endDate].",".$endMoAry[1]); 
// add 23hrs, 59 seconds, to make day end at 11:59pm, rather than 12am
$end_ts=$end_ts+86399;

include("session_tracker.inc.php");
/***************************************************
Connect to database
***************************************************/
include("mysql_access_db.php");

/***************************************************
Get oldest/newest record date from DB
***************************************************/
$query = "SELECT CalendarDate
FROM Calendar";
    
$result = mysql_query ($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
// convert to timestamp
$cal_date_timestamp = strtotime($row[CalendarDate]);

  if(empty($oldest_record))
  {
     $oldest_record = strtotime($row[CalendarDate]);
  }

  if($cal_date_timestamp < $oldest_record)
  {
    $oldest_record = $cal_date_timestamp;
  }

  if(empty($newest_record))
  {
    $newest_record = strtotime($row[CalendarDate]);
  }

  if($cal_date_timestamp > $newest_record)
  {
    $newest_record = $cal_date_timestamp;
  }

  // build array of all values
  $cal_date_timestamp_array[] = $cal_date_timestamp;
}

 $cal_date_timestamp_array =array_unique($cal_date_timestamp_array);
 sort($cal_date_timestamp_array);
 // unique timestamps
 foreach($cal_date_timestamp_array as $tk=>$tv)
 {
   // echo "$tk $tv<br>";
   $cal_dt_ary[]= date ( "D, M d, Y", $tv);
   $cal_moYr_ary[]= date ( "F Y", $tv);
   $cal_mo_ary[]= date ( "F", $tv);
   $cal_yr_ary[]= date ( "Y", $tv);
 }

 // unique full dates
 $cal_dt_ary =array_unique($cal_dt_ary);
 foreach($cal_dt_ary as $tk1=>$tv1)
 {
   // echo "$tk1 $tv1<br>";
 }
 // unique months
 $cal_mo_ary =array_unique($cal_mo_ary);
 foreach($cal_mo_ary as $tk2=>$tv2)
 {
   //echo "$tk2 $tv2<br>";
 }
 // unique years
 $cal_yr_ary =array_unique($cal_yr_ary);
 foreach($cal_yr_ary as $tk3=>$tv3)
 {
   //echo "$tk3 $tv3<br>";
 }
  // unique month/year combinations
  $cal_moYr_ary = array_unique($cal_moYr_ary);
 foreach($cal_moYr_ary as $tk4=>$tv4)
 {
   //echo "$tk4 $tv4<br>";
 }

$oldest_record = array_shift($cal_date_timestamp_array);

$newest_record = array_pop($cal_date_timestamp_array);
// echo date ( "D, M d, Y", $newest_record);

/***************************************************
establish start of date range
If start_ts is not present, use oldest record in db as start date;
otherwise, use GET value for start date
***************************************************/
//$timestamp_minus30 = strtotime("-30 days");
if(empty($start_ts))
{
  $timestamp_minus30 = $oldest_record;
}
elseif(!empty($start_ts))
{
  $timestamp_minus30 = $start_ts;
}

/***************************************************
establish end of date range
***************************************************/
//$timestamp = time();
$timestamp = $newest_record;

//echo "Start date: ";
//$start_month_m=date ("m" , $oldest_record); // month as numeral with leading zero

if(empty($start_ts))
{
  $start_month_m=date ("m" , $oldest_record); // month as numeral with leading zero
}
elseif(!empty($start_ts))
{
  $start_month_m=date ("m" , $start_ts); // month as numeral with leading zero
}

$start_month_n=date ("n" , $oldest_record); // month as numeral without leading zero
$start_month_F=date ("F" , $oldest_record); // month as lonf text string (e.g. 'January')
$start_day_d=date ("d", $oldest_record);
$start_year_Y=date ("Y" , $oldest_record);

$end_month_m=date ("m" , $newest_record);
$end_month_n=date ("n" , $newest_record);

$end_month_F=date ("F" , $newest_record);
$end_day_d=date ("d", $newest_record);
$end_year_Y=date ("Y" , $newest_record);

// names of months
$month_array[]= "January";
$month_array[]= "February";
$month_array[]= "March";
$month_array[]= "April";
$month_array[]= "May";
$month_array[]= "June";
$month_array[]= "July";
$month_array[]= "August";
$month_array[]= "September";
$month_array[]= "October";
$month_array[]= "November";
$month_array[]= "December";

// START date
// February;check for leap year

if($start_month_m==2)
{
  if(date("L",$newest_record) == 1)
  {
    $start_date_end = 29;
  }
  elseif(date("L",$newest_record) == 0)
  {
    $start_date_end = 28;
  }
}

// months with 30 days
elseif($start_month_m==4 || $start_month_m==6 || $start_month_m==9 || $start_month_m==11)
{
  $start_date_end = 30;
}

// months with 31 days
elseif($start_month_n==1 || $start_month_n==3 || $start_month_n==5 || $start_month_n==7 || $start_month_n==8 || $start_month_n==10 || $start_month_n==12)
{
  $start_date_end = 31;
}

$start_date_begin = 1;
$end_date_begin = 1;
// END date
// February;check for leap year
if($end_month_n==2)
{
  if(date("L",$newest_record) == 1)
  {
    $end_date_end = 29;
  }
  elseif(date("L",$newest_record) == 0)
  {
    $end_date_end = 28;
  }
}

// months with 30 days
elseif($end_month_n==4 || $end_month_n==6 || $end_month_n==9 || $end_month_n==11)
{
  $end_date_end = 30;
}

// months with 31 days
elseif($end_month_n==1 || $end_month_n==3 || $end_month_n==5 || $end_month_n==7 || $end_month_n==8 || $end_month_n==10 || $end_month_n==12)
{
  $end_date_end = 31;
}

else
{
  $end_date_end = "";
}

/***************************************************
Scrub user-submitted data
NOTE: Since it's a GET function ALL data can be submitted by the user
in the location window
***************************************************/
if($_GET)
{

  while($_GET[searchInput] != strip_tags($_GET[searchInput])) 
  {
    $_GET[searchInput] = strip_tags($_GET[searchInput]);
  }
}
?>
<form name="formSearchMeetings"  action="<?php echo $page_name; ?>" method="GET" >
<input type="hidden" name="v" value="<?php echo $_GET[v];?>">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="meetingcaltable">
<tr>
<td colspan="9" align="left" valign="top"><span class="textHeadlines">
Appointments</span>  from <?php echo $start_month_F . " " .  $start_day_d . ", " .  $start_year_Y . " to " . $end_month_F . " " .  $end_day_d . ", " .  $end_year_Y;?> .
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
/***************************************************
Display 'Detail' search buttons ('New Search' and 'Previous Search')
***************************************************/
if(!empty($_GET[vtype]) && $_GET[vtype]=="detail")
{ 
 include "display_detail_search.inc.php";
}
else
{
// determine which, if any, radio button is selected
if($_GET[search_type]=="")                { $sel3="checked"; }
if($_GET[search_type]=="any")             { $sel1="checked"; }
elseif($_GET[search_type]=="leader")        { $sel2="checked"; }
elseif($_GET[search_type]=="meeting_num")    { $sel3="checked"; }
elseif($_GET[search_type]=="party")       { $sel4="checked"; }
elseif($_GET[search_type]=="short_title") { $sel5="checked"; }
?>
<tr class="odd">
<td colspan="9" align="left" valign="top">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap><b>Search by:&nbsp; </b></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="meeting_num" <?php echo $sel3;?>></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap><b>&nbsp;Reason Num.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="short_title" <?php echo $sel5;?>></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap>&nbsp;Reason Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="party" <?php echo $sel4;?>></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap>&nbsp;Party name&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="atty" <?php echo $sel2;?>></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap>&nbsp;Responcibility&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" ><input type="radio" name="search_type" value="any" <?php echo $sel1;?>></td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap>&nbsp;MeetingRoom/Date&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="9" align="left" valign="top">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="LEFT" valign="top"><b>Search for:&nbsp;</b></td>
<td align="LEFT" valign="top"><input type="text" name="searchInput" <?php if(!empty($_GET[searchInput])) { echo "value =\"$_GET[searchInput]\""; } ?>size="27"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"></td>
<td align="LEFT" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="search_scope" value="broad" <?php if($_GET[search_scope]=="broad" || $_GET[search_scope]=="") { echo "checked"; } ?>></td>
<td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;Single or partial word or number &nbsp;</td>
<td align="LEFT" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="search_scope" value="strict" <?php if($_GET[search_scope]=="strict") { echo "checked"; } ?>></td>
<td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;exact phrase&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="LEFT" valign="top"></td>
<td colspan="6" align="LEFT" valign="top">(e.g. 12345 or SFL-12345; DOE or DOE, JOHN etc.)</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td colspan="9" align="left" valign="top">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top"><b>By Meetingroom:&nbsp; </b></td>
<td align="right" valign="top"><?php
/***************************************************
query for Meetingroom menu
***************************************************/
buildCtrmMenu();
?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="9" align="left" valign="top">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top"><b>By Date:&nbsp;</b></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><?php
/***************************************************
// START date select menu
***************************************************/
// if no month is selected, use default start
$i_begin_start_date = $start_date_begin;
$end_date_end=31; // set all months to have 31 days
// otherwise use selected month

echo "<select name=\"startDate\">";
// echo"<option  value=\"\">Start Date</option>\n";
while(trim($i_begin_start_date) <= $end_date_end)
{
  echo "<option value=\"$i_begin_start_date\"";
  // match submitted end date, if any.
  // make sure Get[endDate] is NOT empty; otherwise it'll use the default setting to select the date,
  if(!empty($_GET[startDate]) && $_GET[startDate] == $i_begin_start_date)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
  }                                    
  // default to selecting current day/date
  elseif(empty($_GET[startDate]) && $start_day_d == $i_begin_start_date)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
  }
  // Do nothing...
  else {}

  if($i_begin_start_date==1 || $i_begin_start_date==21 || $i_begin_start_date==31) {
  $dt_end="st";
  }
  elseif($i_begin_start_date==2 || $i_begin_start_date==22) {
  $dt_end="nd";
  }
  elseif($i_begin_start_date==3 || $i_begin_start_date==23) {
  $dt_end="rd";
  }                                                                        
  elseif($i_begin_start_date>=4 && $i_begin_start_date <=20 || $i_begin_start_date>=24 && $i_begin_start_date<=30) {
  $dt_end="th";
  } 
  echo ">$i_begin_start_date$dt_end</option>\n";
  $i_begin_start_date++;
}
echo "</select>\n";
?></td>
<td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;day of
<?php
$oldest_select = trim(date ( "F Y", $oldest_record));
echo "<select name=\"startMonth\">";
foreach($cal_moYr_ary as $tk4=>$tv4)
{
  echo "<option value=\"$tv4\"";
  if(!empty($_GET[startMonth]) && $_GET[startMonth]  == $tv4)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
  }                                    
  // default to selecting current day/date
  elseif(empty($_GET[startMonth]) && $oldest_select == $tv4)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
  }
  echo ">$tv4</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>";
?></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"></td>
<td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;to the</td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><?php
/***************************************************
END DATE SELECT MENU
***************************************************/
$i_begin_ending_date = $start_date_begin;
$end_date_end=31; // set all months to 31 days
echo "<select name=\"endDate\">";
while(trim($i_begin_ending_date) <= $end_date_end)
{
   echo "<option value=\"$i_begin_ending_date\"";
  // match submitted end date, if any.
  // make sure Get[endDate] is NOT empty; otherwise it'll use the default setting to select the date,
  if(!empty($_GET[endDate]) && $_GET[endDate] == $i_begin_ending_date)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
  }                                    
  // default to selecting current day/date
  elseif(empty($_GET[endDate]) && $end_day_d == $i_begin_ending_date)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
  }
  // Do nothing...
  else {}

  if($i_begin_ending_date==1 || $i_begin_ending_date==21 || $i_begin_ending_date==31) {
  $dt_end="st";
  }
  elseif($i_begin_ending_date==2 || $i_begin_ending_date==22) {
  $dt_end="nd";
  }
  elseif($i_begin_ending_date==3 || $i_begin_ending_date==23) {
  $dt_end="rd";
}                                                                        
  elseif($i_begin_ending_date>=4 && $i_begin_ending_date <=20 ||  $i_begin_ending_date>=24 && $i_begin_ending_date<=30) {
  $dt_end="th";
  } 
  echo ">$i_begin_ending_date$dt_end</option>\n";
  $i_begin_ending_date++;
}
echo "</select>\n";
unset($error);
?></td>
<td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;day of</td>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<?php
$newest_select = trim(date ( "F Y", $newest_record));
echo "<select name=\"endMonth\">";

foreach($cal_moYr_ary as $tk4=>$tv4)
{
  echo "<option value=\"$tv4\"";
  if(!empty($_GET[endMonth]) && $_GET[endMonth]  == $tv4)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
  }                                    
  // default to selecting current day/date
  elseif(empty($_GET[endMonth]) && $newest_select == $tv4)
  {
    echo " selected " ;
   }
  echo ">$tv4</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>";
?></td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td colspan="9" align="left" valign="top">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" nowrap></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" nowrap><input type="submit" name="submitMeeting" value="Search">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="textSmall">See '<b>Search Tips</b>' in sidebar for help.</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="9" align="left" valign="top">
<?php
} // end if NOT detail view

/***************************************************
DETERMINE WHICH SEARCH TYPE HAS BEEN REQUESTED
http://domain.com/$page_name?v=meetings
&search_type=meeting_num
&dept_search_menu=
&startDate=11
&startMonth=January%202005&endDate=31
&endMonth=March%202005
&searchInput=SCV-232732
&search_scope=strict&
submitMeeting=Search
&vtype=detail
***************************************************/

if(!empty($_GET[vtype]) && $_GET[vtype]=="detail")
{ 
  //echo "detail...";
  include("meetings_detail.inc.php"); 
}

// if NOT detail view request...
elseif(empty($_GET[vtype]) || $_GET[vtype]!="detail")
{                               
  //if(!empty($_GET[search_type]) && $_GET[vtype]!="detail")
  if(!empty($_GET[search_type]) )
  {
    if($_GET[search_type]=="meeting_num")
    {
    // echo "search for meeting_num";
    if(!empty($_GET[searchInput]))
    {
    include("meetingsqueryreasonnum.inc.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "<b> ERROR. No Meeting Number entered. ";
    }
    }
    elseif($_GET[search_type]=="short_title")
    {
    // echo "search for short_title";
    if(!empty($_GET[searchInput]))
    {
    include("meetings_query_shorttitle.inc.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "<b> ERROR. No Meeting Name entered. ";
    }
    }
    elseif($_GET[search_type]=="atty")
    {
    if(!empty($_GET[searchInput]))
    {
    include("T_meetings_query_responsible.inc.php");
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "<b> ERROR. No Meeting Leader Name entered. ";
    }
    }
    elseif($_GET[search_type]=="party")
    {
      if(!empty($_GET[searchInput]))
      {
        include("meetings_query_party.inc.php");
      }
      else 
      {
        echo "<b> ERROR. No Attendee Name entered. ";
      } 
    }                 
    elseif($_GET[search_type]=="any" && !empty($_GET[dept_search_menu]))
    {
      include("meetings_query_dept.inc.php");
    }

    elseif($_GET[search_type]=="any" && !empty($_GET[submitMeeting]) && empty($_GET[dept_search_menu]))
    {
      include("meetings_query_date.inc.php");
    } 
  }
  /***************************************************
  Search by Meeting room only
  ***************************************************/

  elseif(empty($_GET[search_type]) && !empty($_GET[dept_search_menu]))
  {
    include("meetings_query_dept.inc.php");
  }
  /***************************************************
  Search by Date Range only
  ***************************************************/

  elseif(!empty($_GET[submitMeeting]) && empty($_GET[search_type]) && empty($_GET[dept_search_menu]))
  {
    include("meetings_query_date.inc.php");
  }         

  } // end if NOT detail view         


?></td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
/***************************************************
FUNCTIONS
***************************************************/

/***************************************************
Build select menu for 'Courtrooms'
***************************************************/
function buildCtrmMenu()
{
// get list of active courtrooms from db
$queryDEPT = "SELECT * 
FROM MeetingroomList
WHERE MeetingroomList.CtrmNameName != \"\"
";

$resultDEPT = mysql_query ($queryDEPT)
or die ("Cannot execute query.
<br>error message = " . mysql_error () . " from " . __FILE__ . " on line " . __LINE__);

if (mysql_num_rows ($resultDEPT) == 0)
{
  echo ("No records found ");
}

echo "
<select name=\"dept_search_menu\">\n
<option  value=\"\" $dsel>Any Meetingroom</option>\n";

while($rowDEPT = mysql_fetch_array($resultDEPT))
{
/***************************************************
Write select menu values
***************************************************/
  // If matches selected menu value, mark as selected
  $CtrmNameValue = $rowDEPT[CtrmNameValue];
  if(trim($_GET[dept_search_menu]) == $CtrmNameValue)
  {
    $sel="selected";
  }
  else
  {
    $sel = "";
  }

  echo "
<option value=\"".$rowDEPT[CtrmNameValue]."\" $sel>".$rowDEPT[CtrmNameName]."</option>";
}
echo "
</select>";
}

/***************************************************
DISCLAIMER
***************************************************/
echo "<hr noshade size=\"1\">
<span class=\"textSmall\"><b>Please Note</b>: As the online calendars are
updated once daily, at 5 a.m., Monday-Friday, some current changes may  not be available on-line until the 5 a.m. update. 
If you are unable to find your meeting on-line, or need more information, please contact the Clerks in person, or by phone at xxx-xxx-xxxx.</span>";
/***************************************************
SEARCH TIPS
 ***************************************************/
echo "<br><br><span class=\"textSmall\"><b><a name=\"tips\">Search Tips:</a></b></br>
1) If you know the meeting number, use meeting number search for fastest results (e.g. SFL-12345 or 12345)<br>
2) If you know the meeting name, type in part of meeting name (e.g. JOHN)<br>
3) If you want to search by party's name or leaders's name:<br>
- Typically party/leader's name is entered as Lastname, Firstname (i.e. DOE, JOHN) and it is not case sensitive.<br>
- If you don't find your record, try typing  DOE only or JOHN only and narrow the search results using the date range.</span><br>";
/***************************************************
If request is for 'detail' view, display note on how to see Calendar Type Abbr. explanation
***************************************************/
if($_GET[vtype]==detail)
{
 echo "<span class=\"textSmall\">4) Hold mouse over 'CAL. TYPE' abbreviation for explanation.</span><br>";
}
 /***************************************************
how long the report took to generate...
***************************************************/
$end_time = getmicrotime();
$report_seconds = "<br><span class=\"tinyText\">Meeting query completed in ". substr($end_time-$start_time,0,5)." seconds</span>\n";
echo "$report_seconds";

// display session variables
foreach($_SESSION as $ks=>$vs)
{
  // echo "$ks $vs<br>";
}

/***************************************************
// Simple function for retrieving the current timestamp in microseconds
***************************************************/
function getmicrotime()
{
  list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ",microtime());
  return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
?>
```

#### Research

Things that are not the answer....

> In doing other research, I found how to check the syntax of the files by using `php -l <filename>`.  Trying this on both the common.inc and the php file for the body of the page resulted in `"No syntax errors"` for each.

~

> Why this is not answered by [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them):
>
> I looked at this article before I posted.  Good article. Problem is that
>
> 1. the file in question was not just created, it worked just fine before.
> 2. Barring that I've looked as best I can and there are no missing or misplace syntax.
> 3. Include is not used anywhere in the file! While it is written in the comments and there are references to the includes directory, the instruction include IS NOT USED!  And yes, I've checked to make sure that the comments are comments and an include is not sticking out somewhere.

~

> Why this is not answered by [T_INCLUDE - Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938992/t-include-issue) :
>
> Again include is not in the file as a command.  Neither is *DIR*.  All the semi-colons are there  all the quotations are there.  This file worked before the upgrade.  This file works on pages where there is no PHP code.  This answer does not answer my question.

Comment: You really expect someone to read all this?

Comment: u_mulder: No, I'm "HOPING" that someone that has more experience than I will point me in the direction of how I might go about trouble shooting this issue.  I've included the code so that I'm not told to include code by those that glance at questions and then think they are helping but replying "Post Code"

Comment: zod:  As that post points out the error on a line that actually has the indicated text and mine does not,  I'm unsure how this would be a duplicate posting.

Comment: What is on `common.inc` line 1695?  What is the first `include` call in the `common.inc` file?

Comment: Try switching to original drupal theme and see is this still happening. If not, problem is in your theme. If it is, try turning of modules. If you turn all modules you added and it's still happening then you installation is most likely broken - reinstall. It can also be wrong PHP version...

Comment: New Alexandria:  1694  =  ob_start();
1695 =  print eval('?>'. $code);
1696 =  $output = ob_get_contents();

Comment: MilanG:  The hosting company did just upgrade the PHP so it's possible it is the wrong version.  I'll have to wait until this evening to change out the modules as we only have a live system (hate having no test environment). When you say the wrong PHP version, are you saying that Drupal and PHP are incompatible or something else?

Comment: @C.MichaelWarden http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?489948-eval%28%29-php-include-not-working might help

Comment: @C.MichaelWarden I suspect that something in `print eval('?>'. $code);`, specifically, the code that is being passed to from `$code` may use `include` incorrectly. You may need to find out what code is being passed to `eval()` to see if it's correct. The article I linked to previously suggests that when an include is passed to `eval()`, it should be `include ''` and not `include('')`. As was said, since this may be an older version of Drupal, you may want to see if it can be upgraded or reinstalled to a new version.